# LOAD DATA FROM CSV FILE

Tags: mysql, macos, csv, load, macos-catalina

I am using MacOS for Catalina MySQL.

When I enter the following in Terminal

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE ‘/Users/MyData/MDRC/Bible Modules/Crosswire_kjv_002.csv’ INTO TABLE tbl_texts_kjv_from_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

the response is:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘/Users/MyData/MDRC/Bible Modules/Crosswire_kjv_002.csv’ INTO TABLE tbl_text' at line 1
```

But my input seems to match the refman-8.0-en.pdf. It also seems to match the recomendation in 'Learning MySQL' from O'reilly. I have tried various variations of input, all with the same response.

The file `mysql-errors-8.0-en.a4.pdf` says:

```
Error number: 1064; Symbol: ER_PARSE_ERROR; SQLSTATE: 42000
Message: %s near '%s' at line %d
```

which tells me nothing more than the response.

Comment: Always turn off "smart quotes" when editing code.

Answer (score 1):

You need  single quote around the file name

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/Users/MyData/MDRC/Bible Modules/Crosswire_kjv_002.csv' INTO TABLE tbl_texts_kjv_from_csv FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I tried the single quotes change,but there was no change. so I turned the smart quotes option off in MacOS, MS Word and Firefox which also produced no change, so I re-typed the complete command and got a different error message. So this seems like progress. the new error message is ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
mysql> which I shall investigate and see where that gets me. Once again thanks for your help